# make inline list items certain width

Tags: html, css

I have the list items with image on the left and text on the right. Since each image is not exactly the same width, the text don't align vertically.
How can I make it so that the labels align vertically, each to the right of its image? Thanks

```css
.checks-row {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checks-row li {
  display: inline;
}

.check-image {
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checks-row">
  <li class="check-image">
    <img src="/{{this.image}}.gif">
  </li>
  <li class="check-label">{{this.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle, that would be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following css:

```
.checks-row li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```